# Rolling up multiple rows into one in SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I roll the values (preferably using PL/SQL) in different columns for same person A into one column?

I want to convert this:

```
    NAME  SUB1  SUB2    SUB3    SUB4
     A                          PASS
     A                  PASS    
     A          PASS        
     A   PASS
```

into :

```
     NAME   SUB1    SUB2    SUB3    SUB4
      A     PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS
```

I tried to use 'stuff' funciton but that would only be good to club all values under one field. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure? This can be done using plain SQL

Answer (score 4):

Bunch of MAXs does the job (at least, according to what you posted so far).

```
SQL> with test (name, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4) as
  2    (select 'a', null, null, null, 'pass' from dual union all
  3     select 'a', null, null, 'pass', null from dual union all
  4     select 'a', null, 'pass', null, null from dual union all
  5     select 'a', 'pass', null, null, null from dual
  6    )
  7  select name, max(sub1) sub1, max(sub2) sub2, max(sub3) sub3, max(sub4) sub4
  8  from test
  9  group by name;

N SUB1 SUB2 SUB3 SUB4
- ---- ---- ---- ----
a pass pass pass pass

SQL>
```

By the way, did you actually mean to say "preferably using **SQL**"? Why would you involve PL/SQL?